# How do I setup correct testing for axios in React?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, axios, enzyme

I'm using axios in React and I'm having problems with testing

This is what I've tried so far in my test.js file:

```
jest.mock('axios');

describe('RssFeed', () => {
  let component;
  let data;

  beforeEach( () => {
    data = data {
      data: {...}
    };
  }

  test('fetches data successfully', (done) => {
    axios.get.mockResolvedValue(data);
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(axios).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

This is how I have the axios.get setup in my component:

```
const [feedBody, setFeedBody] = useState([]);
const apiUrl = 'apiUrl';

useEffect( () => {
  axios.get(apiUrl)
       .then((response) => (response.data))
       .then((data) => {
         setFeedBody(data);
       })
       .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}, []);
```

After I run my tests, I get:

> Error: Uncaught [Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
> Expected number of calls: >= 1
> Received number of calls:    0]

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65336283/i-want-to-write-unit-test-for-my-react-component-the-logic-what-i-want-to-test-i
I had something similar to this .May be this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `axios-mock-adapter`, it's very handy:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
const resp = 'success';
const testInput = 'testInput';
mock.onGet().reply(200, resp);

// expect feedBody to be 'success'

mock.reset();
```